# Missing input files for rule all in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to construct a snakemake pipeline for biosynthetic gene cluter detection but am struggling with the error:

```
Missing input files for rule all:
antismash-output/Unmap_09/Unmap_09.txt
antismash-output/Unmap_12/Unmap_12.txt
antismash-output/Unmap_18/Unmap_18.txt
```

And so on with more files. As far as I can see the file generation in the snakefile should be working:

```
    workdir: config["path_to_files"]
wildcard_constraints:
    separator = config["separator"],
    extension = config["file_extension"],
    sample = config["samples"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("antismash-output/{sample}/{sample}.txt", sample = config["samples"])

# merging the paired end reads (either fasta or fastq) as prodigal only takes single end reads
rule pear:
    input:
        forward = "{sample}{separator}1.{extension}",
        reverse = "{sample}{separator}2.{extension}"

    output:
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}"

    conda:
        "~/miniconda3/envs/antismash"

    shell:
        "pear -f {input.forward} -r {input.reverse} -o {output} -t 21"

# If single end then move them to merged_reads directory
rule move:
    input:
        "{sample}.{extension}"

    output:
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}"

    shell:
        "cp {path}/{sample}.{extension} {path}/merged_reads/"

# Setting the rule order on the 2 above rules which should be treated equally and only one run.
ruleorder: pear > move
# annotating the metagenome with prodigal#. Can be done inside antiSMASH but prefer to do it out
rule prodigal:
    input:
        "merged_reads/{sample}.{extension}"

    output:
        gbk_files = "annotated_reads/{sample}.gbk",
        protein_files = "protein_reads/{sample}.faa"

    conda:
        "~/miniconda3/envs/antismash"

    shell:
        "prodigal -i {input} -o {output.gbk_files} -a {output.protein_files} -p meta"

# running antiSMASH on the annotated metagenome
rule antiSMASH:
    input:
        "annotated_reads/{sample}.gbk"

    output:
        touch("antismash-output/{sample}/{sample}.txt")

    conda:
        "~/miniconda3/envs/antismash"

    shell:
        "antismash --knownclusterblast --subclusterblast --full-hmmer --smcog --outputfolder antismash-output/{wildcards.sample}/ {input}"
```

This is an example of what my config.yaml file looks like:

```
file_extension: fastq
path_to_files: /home/lamma/ABR/Each_reads
samples:
- Unmap_14
- Unmap_55
- Unmap_37
separator: _
```

I can not see where i am going wrong within the snakefile to produce such an error. Apologies for the simple question, I am new to snakemake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you setup your global wildcard constraints wrong:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    separator = config["separator"],
    extension = config["file_extension"],
    sample = '|'.join(config["samples"])  # <-- this should fix the problem
```

Then immediatly another problem follows with `extension` and `seperator` wildcards. Snakemake can only infer what these should be from other filenames, you can not actually set these through wildcard constraints. We can make use of `f-string` syntax to fill in what the values should be:

```
rule pear:
    input:
        forward = f"{{sample}}{config['separator']}1.{{extension}}",
        reverse = f"{{sample}}{config['separator']}2.{{extension}}"
    ...
```

and:

```
rule prodigal:
    input:
        f"merged_reads/{{sample}}.{config['file_extension']}"
    ...
```

Take a look at snakemake [regex](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards) if the wildcard constraints confuse you, and find a blog about f-strings if you are confused about the `f""` syntax and when to use single `{` and when to use double `{{` to escape them.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You sir are a damn genius! Thatnk you very much!! I will take a look ta the recourses you suggesting so I can learn for next time :)

Comment: That constraint is an amazing trick. I've been looking for something like that for a long time!

Answer (score 0):

(Since I can't comment yet ...)
You might have a problem with your relative paths, and we cannot see where your files actually are found.

A way to debug this is to use `config["path_to_files"]` to create absolute paths in `input:`
That would give you better error message on where Snakemake expects the files - input/output files are relative to the working directory.